# creating a set of parents without specific children

Tags: jquery

I have 500 `<p>` elements, each with about 500 `<span>` elements with their css set to opacity 1.

If I `$('p').css( 'opacity', .5 )`, everything is updated in an instant.

If I `$('p span').css( 'opacity', .5 )`, it takes a few seconds to update.  Obviously.  It is iterating over every element.

My question is: given an arbitrary set of `<span>` elements in different `<p>` elements, is there a good way to make *everything but those spans* change to opacity .5?

I tried [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
`$('p').not( $('p span').slice( 5, 600) ).css( 'opacity', .5 )` does not work -- probably because I am performing set algebra to remove children from parents.  I was hoping it would implicitly work.  Alas.

Is there a good way to solve this type of problem?  [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNU62/8/).

`$('p span').not( $('p span').slice( 5, 600) ).css( 'opacity', .5 )` works ... but it is slow :-/

Comment: Just to make sure, you are wrapping your selectors in quotes right? ... unlike the code you posted...

Comment: Your code should work (if you add the single quotes to your not selector). Any example somewhere?

Comment: @jedierikb ugh, probably give a smaller set as an example? Opening your fiddle freezes my browser by a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `jQuery` method after `slice`:

http://jsfiddle.net/CNU62/10/

```
$('p span').slice(5, 600).css('opacity', .75);
```

EDIT:

If you don't mind doing two steps:

http://jsfiddle.net/CNU62/13/

```
$('p span').slice(10, 20).addClass('filterOut');
$('span').not('.filterOut').css('opacity', .75);
```

Basically add special class to those spans you sliced, and you `not` to take out `span`s with the classes, then do `css()`

Comment: I want _everything but those spans_, the sliced spans, to change their opacity.

Comment: If you increase the # of ps and spans to 500, chrome gets Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.  Iterating over a lot of spans...

Comment: that works, but is 4-6x slower than http://stackoverflow.com/a/12084769/62255  see http://jsfiddle.net/V62wp/9/

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this will perform well with so many elements, you can you can do this:

```
$("p > *").not("span").css("opacity", 0.5);
```

This will get all children objects of the `<p>` tags and then remove the `<span>` elements from that collection before applying the opacity.  So only the `<span>` elements will remain unaffected inside the `<p>`tags.

FYI, if you need it to perform well, then walking the tree directly would probably be many times faster than this.  There are some places where direct JS code can just be so much faster than what you can do in a selector operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt... still pretty slow.

http://jsfiddle.net/V62wp/5/

```
var specialSpans = $('p span').slice(5, 105);
$('p').not(specialSpans.parent()).css('opacity', .5);
specialSpans.siblings().not( specialSpans ).css( 'opacity', .5 );
```

---

This gives a slight speed increase (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8KNV/4/)):

```
var specialSpans = $('p span').slice(5, 105);
var specialParent = specialSpans.parent();
$('p').not(specialParent).css('opacity', .5);
specialParent.children().not(specialSpans).css('opacity', .5);
```